# Multiple window application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for a cocoa example that illustrates how to create a multi-window app. Two windows, two nibs. Clicking a button in one window shows another window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a controller to own the one window and the controller for the other window, and have the first controller respond to the button's action message by telling the second controller to show its window.

The second controller can be a vanilla NSWindowController; the first one will need to be custom or a subclass in order to own the second controller and to implement the action method.